# mysqldbcopy combining foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql

So I currently have a table that has the following constraints according to `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_BA62400997790DEE` FOREIGN KEY (`some_id`) REFERENCES `Other_Table` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_BA624009C8554709` FOREIGN KEY (`someOther_id`) REFERENCES `Yet_Another_Table` (`id`)
```

However, when using `mysqldbcopy` to copy the db over, I get the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE old_database.OriginalTable add CONSTRAINT `FK_BA62400997790DEE`
FOREIGN KEY (`some_id`,`someOther_id`)
REFERENCES `old_database`.`Other_Table`
(`id`,`id`)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT
. Error: Query failed. 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'old_database.#sql-602_4b5' (errno: 150)
```

Something is clearly going wrong here, but not sure what it is. Clearly it's somehow trying to combine the keys?

I am running version 1.3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1.3.6 release fixed the following bug which may be related

```
BUG#17474810: constraint error copying the employees with mysqldbcopy
```

Try upgrading to something higher, currently up to version 1.6 - https://launchpad.net/mysql-utilities

Comment: what a shame that ubuntu 14.04 is still on 1.3.5

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 14.04, install http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-mysql.connector and http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mysql-utilities and you should be able to work around this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I am using MySQL Utilities mysqldbcopy version 1.6.5, it still shows me something like this:

```
ERROR: Unable to execute constraint query
ALTER TABLE node5.books add CONSTRAINT `books_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
REFERENCES `node5`.`publishers`
(`id`)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT
. Error: Query failed. 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

And then I found setting storage engine to InnoDB can solve this issue.

https://github.com/maghead/maghead/commit/b406abf277b525f665966f8e8ec421a229bb13c7