# How to upgrade mysql-utilities on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to use mysqldbcopy but receive a constraint error due to 1.3 mixing foreign keys together during the copying process. Exactly what this person described: [mysqldbcopy combining foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351407/mysqldbcopy-combining-foreign-key-constraints)

Apparently this issue was fixed in later versions. Current is 1.6 I believe.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and MySql 5.6 on my local and live server. On my local server, I tried following various ideas on the MySql web site but it simply broke things. Can someone outline a method for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 1.6 versions do the following

```
sudo apt-get remove python-mysql.connector mysql-utilities

wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/db/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-py3_2.0.4-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb`

sudo dpkg -i mysql-connector-python_2.0.4-1ubuntu14.10_all.deb

wget https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-utilities_1.6.5-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i mysql-utilities_1.6.5-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue I was having. First, I had to remove installed packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-mysql.connector mysql-utilities
```

Then download and install the packages I needed:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-connector-python_2.0.4-1ubuntu14.10_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-utilities_1.5.5-1ubuntu15.04_all.deb
```